# How to test express middleware with event emitters

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for an express middleware with event emitters using http-proxy, sinon & rewire.   The issue I'm running into is when I stub the external module (in this case `http-proxy`) when it reaches the `event.on` line it fails because its undefined.

Heres a snippet of source code:

```
let middleware = function(options) {
    proxy.__proto__ = middleware;
    proxy.proxy = buildProxy(extend({}, DEFAULT_OPTIONS, options));  
    _options = options || {};

    proxy.proxy.on('error', function(e, req, res) { // <--- Cannot read property of undefined
        logger(req, res, e);
    });
    proxy.proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
        logger(req, proxyRes);
    });
    return proxy;
};

// This method is stubbed
let buildProxy = function(options) {
    return httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);  // http-proxy module
};
```

Snippet of the test code:

```
it.only('should call buildProxy and pass along options', () => {
    const testOptions = { someOption: true }

    let applicationUnderTest = rewire(UNDER_TEST);
    let methodUnderTest = applicationUnderTest.__get__('middleware');
    let buildProxySpy = sinon.spy();

    applicationUnderTest.__set__('buildProxy', buildProxySpy);

    methodUnderTest(testOptions)

    expect(buildProxySpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
})
```

I was looking for suggestions on how to work around this issue.

Test results:

```
 1) Proxy legacy/integration tests should call buildProxy and pass along options:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instruct your spy to return something when called. With sinon, this will actually be a stub:

```
...
let buildProxySpy = sinon.stub();
buildProxySpy.returns({
  proxy: { on: sinon.spy() }
});
...
```

And of course, you'll want to write additional tests that verify the calls to that returned objects methods, and tests to verify the behavior of the methods passed to the spy returned by the stub.